# Evaluating integral of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Evalute the following integral.

$$ \int \tan^3x \; dx $$

My try :

$$ \int \tan^3x \; dx $$
$$ \int \tan^2x\ \tan x\; dx $$
$$ \int (\sec^2x\ -\ 1)\ \tan x\; dx$$

I couldn't continue. What should i do next ?

Comment: Hint: a [reduction formula](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/moretrigpower/moretrigpower.html) let's you replace the 3 by 1.

Comment: That's what i did !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int(\sec^2x-1)\tan x\; dx\\
=\int \sec^2x \tan x\; dx-\int \tan x \;dx\\
=\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+\ln(\cos x)+c$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\int(\sec^2x-1)\tan x\space dx = \int (\sec^2x\tan x-\tan x) \space dx\int\sec^2x\tan x \space dx-\int \tan x \space dx$$
Use the fact that: $$\frac{d}{dx}\tan x=\sec^2x\\\text{and}\\\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
Then since the function and its derivative is present you can integrate..

$$u=\tan x \implies du=\sec^2x\space dx \\\int\sec^2x\tan x\space dx=\int u\space du$$ 
$$u=\cos x\implies du=-\sin x \space dx\\\int\tan x\space dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\space dx=-\int \frac{du}{u}$$